# How to get list of current wordpress categories and inject each in script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create php code that will get the list of categories that are assigned to a wordpress post (of the current page) and then loop through the array list and each category that IS has been assigned to the post and add it to the script.

this is the script i need to inject the category name in:

```
<script> window.abkw = '<category name>';</script>
```

so i wrote this but it does not seem to work...

```
<?php 
   $ads = the_category();
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($ads); ++$i) {
      $d = $ads[$i];
      <script> window.abkw = $d[$i];</script> 
}
?>here
```

I'm new to php so please excuse my ignorance... and thank you so much.!

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand?  can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

use `get_categories()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

```
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0'));
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<script> window.abkw = '.$category->cat_name.';</script> ';
}
```

Comment: when i run this i receive the following error:  

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/dkjjkabcc988/public_html/news/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 4

Comment: yup - i entered 

<?php 
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0'));
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<script>window.abkw = '.$category->cat_name.'</script> ';
}
?>

and i get the error: 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/site/public_html/news/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 4

please help!!  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: i think you had an extra ' after the 0 in the $categories line...  only issue now is it looks like this spits out all the categories- i want it to list only the categories assigned to the post.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use jquery data()...

https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

--edited--

I expand the way

template-example.php

```
...

<?php
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0'));
foreach($categories as $category): ?>
  <div class="js-category" style="visibility:hidden;" data-category = "<?php echo $category->cat_name ?>"></div> //invisible div
<?php endforeach; ?>
...
```

file.js

```
var categories = $(".js-category").data("category");
```

...

Comment: oh -- i don't know ;)  I'm not really a good dev guy ... so you lost me ... :(

Comment: U can pull all the information from html5 code to js with this way

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I don't understand. In theory I do but I don't know how to make that work with wordpress.   weird. i can get the list - as in my original code - but i can't get it in the script.  I think i'm close but.. :(  I'm at my limit level too :(

Comment: cool... i will test .. now question -   so i put the above code in the template and file.js files?   where does it or do i add the part about add ing it to the scirpt ?   and thank you... i'm sorry i'm such a newbie..  :(

Comment: you can use the data() inside any script (if you have jquery able in your site) use it inside the <script> if you want... And be sure HTML is loaded before. If not you need wrap in $(document).ready() ...
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: yah, i'm looking at your code and i don't see where it added it to the scirpt?   echo '<script> window.abkw = '.$category->cat_name.';</script> ';  or ?     THANK YOU!

Comment: lol you lost me again :(   could you please finish this one off..  and while looping through the categories when you find one that is a member of that post then echo it to the script"   <script> window.abkw = <category>;</script>;